# how to use org.apache.commons.io jar file into Java project using Textpad

Tags: java

I have to implement upload resume feature  in my project.I am making Java project using textpad .For uploading ,I have to `import org.apache.commons.io jar` file.Before running project, I have to set path of `org.apache.commons.io` at `cmd prompt`  which I have placed in a folder in my project.I have to set path every time I run the project.Is any other solution so that I can get rid of this problem.I am new Java programmer.Suggestions and help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Raju Sir & vschafer.I will try it.

Comment: I have set **CLASSPATH**.Also added appache jar file into Java lib folder.But still problem is there.

Answer (score 1):

You can set (or append) system property CLASSPATH to include your commons.io jar, so that the jar is automatically included whenever you run your "java" command.

On Linux:
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/usr/local/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar

On Windows:
see http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm

More details on using the CLASSPATH system variable can be found here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html or here http://javarevisited.blogspot.fi/2011/01/how-classpath-work-in-java.html

Answer (score 0):

Adding jar to our java code can be done using following command:

```
SET JRE_HOME=<path to your jre>
%JRE_HOME%\bin\java.exe -jar apache.commons.io.jar
```

Here you need to mention jre home and need to set path for the jar you want to add is.